# Laravel view not found - after clearing every cache

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes

This is the function

```
public function waybills()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    if(isset($user)){
        $uid = $user->id;
        $receives = Receive::where('receiver_code', $uid)->with('clearance')->get();
        $archives = Archive::where('receiver_code', $uid)->get();
        return view("dashboard.receive.waybills", compact('receives', 'archives'));
    }
}
```

and this is the structure of the directory of files

[image]

I tried this following artisan codes

```
php artisan optimize --force
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

and the error `View [dashboard.receive.waybills] not found.`  persists

Comment: Can you try going to your bootstrap/cache folder and deleting config.php?  Also try `composer dumpautoload` and see if that helps

Comment: @hdifen yes it is local yet

Comment: @hdifen I tried `composer dumpautoload`. In `Bootstrap\cache` there are only `packages.php` and `services.php` files, there is no `config.php`. After all the problem has not gone. But I removed the file, recreated it again and it works now !!!!